# Error when using java -cp with jar file

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run a jar file using java -cp   but it keeps giving me error that could not find or load main class.

Here is my bat file

```
:: install.bat
:: run the installer jar as a windows bat file
::
@echo off

:: setup some properties
set CLASSES=.
set JAVA_OPTS=


:: build a basic classpath
set CP="%CLASSES%"

:: locate the java executable
set JAVA_EXE="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
IF EXIST "%JAVA_EXE%" GOTO start
set JAVA_EXE=java.exe

:start
:: show off java version info
echo -------------------------------------------------
"%JAVA_EXE%" -version
REM echo     JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
REM echo     CLASSPATH: %CP%
echo -------------------------------------------------

:: start the program
%JAVA_EXE% %JAVA_OPTS% -cp %CP% -    Djava.util.logging.config.file="./enr_logging.properties" com.company.product.package.MainClass
```

Assuming that my fully qualified class name is com.company.product.package.MainClass and the jar is in the same folder as the .bat file

Comment: As far as I can tell, `CP` is `.` and not the jar file containing the class?

Comment: yes I am specifying the classpath folder as the folder containing the jar. The reason being that I dont want to use the jar name in the script since the jar name will change with next version

Comment: That's not how the classpath works... you need to have the jar in the classpath.

Comment: the jar file is in the same folder

Comment: That doesn't matter. The *file* needs to be in the classpath list. Not the directory where the file is.

Comment: this would be a problem as I dont want to hardcode the jar file name in the installer script. The reason being that the script will need to  be changed with every version of the product and whenever it is released chaging it from SNAPSHOT

Comment: @Nidhish Puthiyadath can't you pass the jar name as an argument ? Or if you don't know the name, use a batch search to get it (`for %%i in (*.jar) do`). Or simply just * instead of the jar name.

Comment: +1 to the batch search option for avoiding jar name changes.  Added benefit, especially since OP says the batch script is to guard against future updates, is that if new releases have additional classpath requirements (other jars) they will be auto-included (assuming `for` loop builds `-cp` value via concatenation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a jar with `-cp` requires the classpath to list the jar, for instance :

```
java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.pretty.MainClass
```

NB : *`Test.jar` can be replaced by `*` to match all jars, but `*.jar` won't work.*

Alternatively, you can run the jar with `-jar`. This method requires the classpath to be defined in the jar's manifest and silently ignores other classpath declarations.

Comment: thanks that worked, I guess that is the only feasible solution for my specific need.